# how do I add phrases to a file without deleting the file

Tags: python

The text file which is a "txt" file. Also, I have separate files for different length phrases (spaces count towards the phrase length) I saw phrases because it can be multiple words, but in the example below I use three letter words all of which are one word. Also, imagine each phrase is on a new line. Each phrase is separated by a comma. Imagine you have a file like this:

```
app,
bar,
car,
eel,
get,
pod,
```

What I want is to be able to add one or more phrases that will be assumed to only contain lowercase alphabetical letters and/or spaces.

For example, let us say I want to add the phrases in this order:

`(cat, bat, car, hat, mom, rat)`

basically, I want to add these phrases to the file without deleting 
the file and making sure no phrases repeat in the file as well as making sure they are alphabetically sorted. Spaces are assumed to be after the letter z in terms of alphabetically sorting them. So after inputting these phrases, the file should look like this:

```
'
app,
bar,
bat,
car,
eel,
get,
hat,
mom,
pod,
rat
'
```

And each file will be assumed to become at least a gigabyte of data. What is the fastest/least memory consuming/etc. So copying the file in order to accomplish this is a no go.

I haven't tried anything that 100% works. I know what to do, I just don't know how to do it. Here are the main points that I need to accomplish.

1) Make sure the phrase(s) are created (using input() function)

2) Open the file of organized words (using "with open(filename)" statements)

3) Put each phrase into the "correct" spot in the file. By "correct" I mean that is alphabetical and is not a repeat.

4) Make sure the file doesn't get deleted.

Here is what I have currently (changed it a bit and it is doing MORE of what I want, but not everything):

```
phrase_to_add = input('Please enter the phrase: ').lower()
with open('/Users/ian/Documents/three_character_phrases.txt') as file:
    unique_phrases = list(file.read().split())
unique_phrases.append(phrase_to_add)
unique_phrases.sort()
list_of_phrases = set()
for phrase in unique_phrases:
    list_of_phrases.add(phrase)
with open('/Users/ian/Documents/three_character_phrases.txt', 'w') as fin:
    for phrase in list_of_phrases:
        fin.write(phrase + '\n')
```

So I started with BOTH files being empty and I added the word 'cow' by putting it into the input and this what the file looked like:

three_character_phrases.txt:

```
cow
```

then I inputted the word "bat" and I got this:

```
bat
cow
```

then I added the word "bawk" (I know it isn't a 3 letter word but I'll take care of making sure the right words go into the right files)

I got this:

```
bawk
bat
cow
```

Comment: But how do I make sure there are no repeats, and doesn't append only add it to the end of the file.

Comment: Adding dsta without deleting means appending and this can be done by opening a file accordingly in mode 'a'. However, your requirement to insert the new data into the dats which already there in the file makes it necessary to rewrite the whole file or to create a new one.

Comment: first, retrieve the data from your file and put it into a list. then add the items from 'input()' into your list. then check for duplicates and order it, and then use a for loop to write to your file.

Comment: But how do I write it to the file in append mode WITHOUT having to write:

filename.write(phrase)

for EVERY single instance?

Oh I see you said use a for loop, but how would I use it correctly cause every time except once I got unexpected results. Assume, I have the list of no repeats, how would I write to the file in append mode using a for loop with each phrase on a new line?

Comment: If you are sure that the data which are already in the file are already correctly sorted, you could even write a new file on the fly by simply iterating over the old file, without reading it completely into memory.

Comment: How would I do that SpghttCd? Also, I am sorry for these probably basic questions, but I am relatively new at Python and I seem to be running into a lot of problems. I have been able to accomplish each necessary step, but each time I do this another problem occurs. It is like whack-a-mole if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Ian for the `append` question, you would just do `file.append("test\n")` and put that in a for loop. also, in that once time it worked properly, why not use that? If they're problems with it, please list it in your question so we can help you more.

Comment: We're talking quite theoretical here - please consider posting a proper [mcve] with which you have concrete questions we can solve.

Comment: Ok, I added an example

Comment: Is the file structure really like this, especially after this edit by @googi? There weren't newlines before. Does the real file really contain `'` at beginning and end? Are there really spaces besides commas as separators?.... Too many uncertainties here to answer correctly so far IMO.

Comment: what problem are you getting with your current solution?

Comment: No, I finally corrected the file structure.

Comment: I also gave an example of what happened.

Comment: oops, the word bar should have been bow

Comment: You know you're reading from file A and writing to files B and C, right?

Comment: @Axiumin_ that won't work, since he's inserting data he should open in write mode, not append+read

Comment: I changed the code. Hopefully this will give clarification or make it easier to give suggestions on how to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting wrapped up in the implementation instead of trying to understand the concept, so let me invite you to take a step back with me.

You have a data structure that resembles a list (since order is relevant) but allows no duplicates.

```py
['act', 'bar', 'dog']
```

You want to add an entry to that list

```py
['act', 'bar', 'cat', 'dog']
```

and serialize the whole thing to file afterwards so you can use the same data between multiple sessions.

First up is to establish your serialization method. You've chosen a plain text file, line delimited. There's nothing wrong with that, but if you were looking for alternatives then a csv, a json, or indeed serializing directly to database might be good too. Let's proceed forward under the assumption that you won't change serialization schemas, though.

It's easy to read from file

```py
from pathlib import Path
FILEPATH = Path("/Users/ian/Documents/three_character_phrases.txt")

def read_phrases():
    with FILEPATH.open(mode='r') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]
```

and it's easy to write to it, too.

```py
# Assume FILEPATH is defined here, and in all future snippets as well.

def write_phrases(phrases):
    with FILEPATH.open(mode='w') as f:
        f.writelines(f'{phrase}\n' for phrase in phrases)
        # this is equivalent to:
        #   text = '\n'.join(phrases)
        #   f.write(text + '\n')
```

You've even figured out how to have the user enter a new value (though your algorithm could use work to make the worst case better. Since you're always inserting into a sorted list, the `bisect` stdlib module can help your performance here for large lists. I'll leave that for a different question though).

Since you've successfully done all the single steps, the only thing holding you back is to put them all together.

```py
phrases = read_phrases()

phrase_to_add = input('Please enter the phrase: ').lower()
if phrase_to_add not in phrases:
    phrases.append(phrase_to_add)
    phrases.sort()  # this is, again, not optimal. Look at bisect!

write_phrases(phrases)
```

Comment: THANK YOU ADAM SMITH! OMG! I would upvote you a 1000 times, because honestly this has been bugging me for so long it is not even funny anymore. Again, THANK YOU! Also, how do I upvote?

Comment: How would I implement the bisect thingy?

Comment: @Ian try it yourself on a little toy application. All the documentation is available in [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). Try implementing `bisect_insert` such that the following program doesn't crash: `import bisect; lst = [1, 2, 3, 10]; bisect_insert(lst, 5); assert lst == [1, 2, 3, 5, 10]`